# FutureBuilder return passed to var Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to store some data inside a ".txt" file into a variable.
To do this I'm using a `FutureBuilder`.
The idea is to handle the reading action (async) with `FutureBuilder` and pass the `FutureBuilder` return to my global variable that will be updated when needed.

```
  Future<String> _read() async {
   try {
   final file = await _localBio;
   String body = await file.readAsString();
   // Read the file.
   return body;
   } catch (e) {
   // If encountering an error, return 0.
   return "Can't read";
 }
}

var bio ="";

String _ReadBio(){
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _read(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      bio=snapshot.data.toString(); //this isn't done
      return Text("");
    }
    else {
      return Text("Error occured");
    }
  }
);
return "";
}
```

Then in the `TextField` I want to show what is stored inside `bio` that should be the content of `"bio.txt"`.

```
child: Text(
 _ReadBio()== "" //always true if no error occured
 ? bio
 : "Tell us something about you...",
 ),
```

But what is showed is the first `bio` value, I don't know why.

Comment: your first bio value is empty right?

Comment: Yes, is "" but not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to read about [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

You are missing the point od `FutureBuilder` because its is a widget to place in a widget tree what you have done is placed on a function that returns a empty string.

Instead you can do it like this,

```
Future<Widget> _readAndBuildBioWidget(){
   return FutureBuilder<String>(
     future: _read(),
     builder: (context, snapshot){
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
         bio=snapshot.data.toString(); //this isn't done
         return Text(bio ?? "");
       }
       else {
         return Text("Error occured");
      }
    }
  );
  return "";
}

@override
void build() {
   return Scaffold(
     child: _readAndBuildBioWidget(),
   );
}
```

Or you can do as below,

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var bio = "";

  Future<String> _read() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localBio;
      String body = await file.readAsString();
      return body;
    } catch (e) {
      return "Can't read";
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _read().then((onValue) => bio = onValue);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(bio ?? "")),
    );
  }
}
```

Note above code snippet I haven't tested. I just wanted to give a rough idea.

Comment: I love you mate <3 ! This is what I was looking for in 2 days! (2nd method) You know, I did what you wrote yesterday but I missed "bio=value" and I wrote it outside the initState() method. Probably that's why it didn't work...If I'm not wrong I wrote it in a String function.